# WordPress. Adding a taxonomy both to users and other content

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

As reported [in this page](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/10/20/custom-user-taxonomies-in-wordpress) adding a taxonomy to a user is very different and more complicated than doing the same job for anoter content.

That's my question: can I add the taxonomy, let's call it "skills", to my users and  to a CPT called JobOffer?

How... in case it's possible?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways. An easy solution is to use Advanced Custom Fields to add taxonomies for a custom post type to users.
Have you already registered the custom post type taxonomy and linked it to the custom post type?

Comment: I realized that I can register the taxonomy twice (with some small differences in the args array) for both the content types.

Now I have to understand why the taxonomy admin page for users lights the Posts label on the left side menu.

Comment: I would avoid two identical taxonomies. By using ACF you would only need to register the taxonomy once for the 'JobOffer' CPT, and then show the exact same taxonomy for users, while keeping the taxonomy 'in sync'.

Comment: Have you registered the custom taxonomy like this:

register_taxonomy( 'skills', array('JobOffer', 'user'), $args );

Comment: Not exactly. 
I registered it like this:    register_taxonomy( 'skills', array('JobOffer'), $args );  register_taxonomy( 'skills', array( 'user'), $args_user ); where $args_user has a couple of specific attributes to manage user count.

Comment: Well, register_taxonomy does not work that way. "Using register_taxonomy() with the same taxonomy, but different object types will result in the already registered object types to be overwritten." You can only register it once, for both object types and with only one array of args.

Comment: Actually, it works also the way I did, but I'll follow your suggestion. 
The problem, as I said, is that once I select "skills" as Users submenu, the Posts label become selected. Do you know why?